# about:blank sources spamming during website load

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

The issue is somewhat difficult to describe, so here is a screenshot of the symptom

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FltNR.jpg

about:blank loads up many times, and I believe this is causing angular to fail. I'm not certain of this but I'm trying to connect the 2 events as related.

Angular will fail to load producing this error:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at Object.e [as invoke]

Any information to help point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those are probably frames. Use the debugger to debug the stack overflow.

Comment: I've discovered a iframe in our navigation repeater that was causing the issue. It was part of a template, and its been hiding there for a while now, producing more about:blanks as more nav items have been added. The iframe isn't needed, crisis adverted. Thanks for your assistance.